# Conditionally hide a Checkout field in WooCommerce based on chosen shipping

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

in WooCommerce, I am trying to hide the **company name field** whenever "delivery to home" is selected. I've tried a bunch of different things.

This is my most recent attempt:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'xa_remove_billing_checkout_fields');

function xa_remove_billing_checkout_fields($fields) {
    $shipping_method ='pakkelabels_shipping_gls1'; // Set the desired shipping method to hide the checkout field(s).
    global $woocommerce;
    $chosen_methods = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
    $chosen_shipping = $chosen_methods[0];

    if ($chosen_shipping == $shipping_method) {
        unset($fields['billing']['billing_company']); // Add/change filed name to be hide
}
    return $fields;
}
```

But all it does is move the **Shipping company** from the first field to the last.

How can I conditionally hide a specific checkout field based on chosen shipping method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it's a live event, you need to use javascript/jQuery to make it work. The Billing company has to be **not required** like in default WooCommerce checkout page.

The following code will hide the "Billing company" field, when "Home delivery" shipping is chosen:

```
// Conditional Show hide checkout fields based on chosen shipping methods
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'conditionally_hidding_billing_company' );
function conditionally_hidding_billing_company(){
    // Only on checkout page
    if( ! ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) ) return;

    // HERE your shipping methods rate ID "Home delivery"
    $home_delivery = 'pakkelabels_shipping_gls1';
    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery(function($){
            // Choosen shipping method selectors slug
            var shipMethod = 'input[name^="shipping_method"]',
                shipMethodChecked = shipMethod+':checked';

            // Function that shows or hide imput select fields
            function showHide( actionToDo='show', selector='' ){
                if( actionToDo == 'show' )
                    $(selector).show( 200, function(){
                        $(this).addClass("validate-required");
                    });
                else
                    $(selector).hide( 200, function(){
                        $(this).removeClass("validate-required");
                    });
                $(selector).removeClass("woocommerce-validated");
                $(selector).removeClass("woocommerce-invalid woocommerce-invalid-required-field");
            }

            // Initialising: Hide if choosen shipping method is "Home delivery"
            if( $(shipMethodChecked).val() == '<?php echo $home_delivery; ?>' )
                showHide('hide','#billing_company_field' );

            // Live event (When shipping method is changed)
            $( 'form.checkout' ).on( 'change', shipMethod, function() {
                if( $(shipMethodChecked).val() == '<?php echo $home_delivery; ?>' )
                    showHide('hide','#billing_company_field');
                else
                    showHide('show','#billing_company_field');
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested and works.

Comment: You are amazing. Just one last thing. The above code does everything it is supposed to, but we have three types of delivery, so I need it to work with one more type of delivery. Any chance you could let me know how to add that to it? I marked your answer as solving the problem.

1. To giftshop (the one you use there)
2. To home address flat_rate3
3. To company address.

We need the above code to also hide the company field on value = flat_rate:3 / label = shipping_method_0_flate_rate3

How would we add that next to the pakkelabels_shipping_gls1, which is the giftshop one.

Comment: Or perhaps it is easier to say if it is not flat_rate:2 hide the billing company field? Flat rate 2 = our deliver to companies, the two others dont need the field.

Comment: @eMikkelsen Change the php `$home_delivery` variable value to `flat_rate:2` and in the jQuery code for the **`if`** statements (2 occurrences) replace `if( $(shipMethodChecked).val() ==`  by `if( $(shipMethodChecked).val() != ` *(so you replace `==` by `!=` 2 times)*… it should work.