# Show or Hide two checkout fields in Woocommerce

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

In Woocommerce checkout form im trying to hide billing_city and billing_address_1 fields first and after I fill the fields postcode and housenumber the other fields (address_1 and city) has to show.

This is the script, but I does not work well and I dont know what I do wrong:

```
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('input#billing_housenumber').change(function(){

        if (this.checked) {
            jQuery('#billing_city').fadeIn();
            jQuery('#billing_city input').val('');           
        } else {
            jQuery('#billing_city').fadeOut();
        }

    });
</script>
<?php
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 2**

There is some errors, mistakes and missing things in your code. Also you should hooked it in a function *(or register it as an external file)*.

I have added at the end a function that add the billing "housenumber" field in checkout *(just for testing purpose)*…

> In the code below I am using some CSS inline styles to hide the billing city and address_1 fields and to show them when they have an additional selector class "on".

Here is a hooked function that will enable this code in checkout only:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'custom_checkout_script' );
function custom_checkout_script() {
    // Only checkout page
    if( ! ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) ) return;

    // CSS Styles (Hidding fields)
    ?>
    <style>
        #billing_city_field, #billing_address_1_field { display:none !important;}
        #billing_city_field.on ,#billing_address_1_field.on { display:block!important;}
    </style>
    <?php 
    // Jquery script
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( function($){
        var a = 'input#billing_housenumber',
            b = 'input#billing_postcode',
            c = '#billing_city_field,#billing_address_1_field';

        // On start
        if( $(a).val() != '' && $(b).val() != '' && ! $(c).hasClass('on') ){
            $(c).css('display','none !important').addClass('on').show();
            console.log('start');
        }

        // On change: If housenumber and postcode fields are filled, we display other hidden fields
        $(a+','+b).on( 'change', function(){
            if ( $(a).val() != '' && $(b).val() != '' && ! $(c).hasClass('on') ) {
                $(c).css('display','none !important').addClass('on').show( 500 );
                console.log('change - in');
            } else if( ( $(a).val() == '' || $(b).val() == '' ) && $(c).hasClass('on') ) {
                $(c).hide( 200, function(){
                    $(c).removeClass('on').css('display','block')
                });
                console.log('change - out');
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

This code has been tested with this temporary additional code, that generates the checkout "housenumber" text field (just for testing purpose):

```
// Add custom checkout field
add_action( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'my_custom_checkout_field' );
function my_custom_checkout_field( $fields ) {

     $fields['billing_housenumber'] = array(
        'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
        'label'     => __('Housenumber ?'),
        'required'  => false,
        'clear'     => true
     );

     return $fields;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).

---

Related: [Show or hide html element on chosen shipping method change in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51739847/show-or-hide-html-element-on-chosen-shipping-method-change-in-woocommerce/51741088#51741088)

Comment: There is one issue. I dont see the housenumber (after a customer purchase a product). So you dont see the housenumber in the mail or in quatation.

Comment: @EminCelen  There is no issue… For that additional code is needed and you should ask a new question.

Comment: Where iv ask that new question in a another page? or this page as a new question"?

Comment: @EminCelen At the top right, you have a blue button: "Ask question" … Click on it… So it will open a completely new question (empty).

Answer (score 0):

There is one step left. I don't see the housenumber (after a customer purchase a product). So you don't see the housenumber in the mail or in invoice.

This is in the e-mail but I don't see more detail for address:

```
/**
  * @hooked WC_Emails::customer_details() Shows customer details
  * @hooked WC_Emails::email_address() Shows email address
  */
 do_action( 'woocommerce_email_customer_details', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );
```